# Tracking Attachement Downloads/Views

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there any way to track how many times an attachment has been viewed and/or downloaded? I am adding attachments using a custom metabox and just want a way to track the file downloads/views. Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The answer is "yes"...but this question is way too broad to give an answer more detailed than that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of attaching the file to mail provide the file name in mail like linked to your download php file when someone clicks on your file name it will redirect to your download php file and there you can provide the force download of that file  and there in php file you can track the users by storing there ips into database or provide some unique id to file link in every mail and store it to database with count= 0 when every time user clicks on file name then update the count.

i have developed a portal similar to wetransfer and i have used this apporach there to achieve the same thing.